# Do small jump discontinuities also count as removable when finding a limit?

Tags: limits, functions, continuity, contest-math

The question I am talking about is:

" f(x)= -sin^2(x) if x is rational
,  sin^2(x) if x is irrational "

The doubt I have is at π, the value of the function is 0, but lets say there was an irrational number 'i' in the right neighborhood of π and a rational number 'q' in the right neighborhood of 'i' (i and q are very close to each other and π), does the jump discontinuity in the limit of said function affect the limit of the function tending to π?

Can I ignore the discontinuity at i and q even if they lie on opposite sides of the x axis if they are very small?

Can I say that this function is continuous at π?

Also if possible please do give similar examples as it would help a lot.

Comment: they don't count as removable. But you can make another argument about continuity.

Comment: i didn't understand what you meant by making another argument

Comment: You can use the epsilon-delta definition to argue that the function is continuos at pi.

Comment: but at other points there is no "removable" discontinuity. you should look at the definition of what it means to be a "removable" discontinuity (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Removable_discontinuity)